# Необходимо вычесть количества разных товаров в Заказе из количества товаров на Товары

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Если две таблицы: Товар, содержащий информацию о товарах; и таблица Заказ, содержащая коды товаров и их количества.
Как вычесть одно из другого? Как должен выглядеть запрос?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот, что я придумал, но он не работает. Неизвестный столб Orders_has_Goods.Goods_id_goods в условии where

```
update mall.Goods set Goods.amount = Goods.amount - Orders_has_Goods.quantity where Goods.id_goods = Orders_has_Goods.Goods_id_goods;
```

Comment: вас апдейт запрос интересует, или селект? заджойнить их да вычесть, сложность-то какая?

Comment: В основе лежит апдейт. Если я сделаю джоин, будут ли внесены результаты в отдельные таблицы?

Comment: дак вам же склад только уменьшить надо, или нет?

Comment: Да, нужно вычесть из Товаров числа, находящиеся в Заказе.

Comment: у вас в таблице заказов то не один ведь заказ, наверное. запрос нужен для какого-то конкретного, или просуммировать по всем?

Comment: В нормальных СУБД это делается с помощью `MERGE`, но в MySQL такого нет (в последней версии только появилось). Вроде какой-то аналог был, посмотрите его.

Comment: @teran Да, для конкретного заказа. В процедуре для этого есть переменная count - она отображает номер заказа. Мне только нужно запрос туда добавить.

Comment: @Dmitry в любой СУБД это сделается простым апдейтом с указанием двух таблиц. вставка данных тут не нужна, merge тут не в тему.

Comment: @DmitryMoskovchenko ну дак и допишите `update table1, table2 ...`

Comment: @teran Какая еще вставка? Вы в курсе вообще, что такое `MERGE`?

Comment: @teran Все нужно сделать в рамках одной таблицы. Есть столбцы с 1) id товаров и 2) количество заказанных единиц, и есть столбцы с 3) id товаров и 4) количеством товаров в наличии (в другой таблице). Нужно, чтобы 2 вычиталось из 4 там, где 1 совпадает с 3.

Comment: @DmitryMoskovchenko и ? Условно `update a, b set a.amount= a.amount- b.quantity where a.id = b.id and b.key = 123`, что значит ваше "в рамках одной таблицы" ?

Comment: @Dmitry очевидно merge объединяет функциональность insert и update, в данном случае нужен только update, так что merge избыточен. не?

Comment: @teran Он не избыточен, потому что он не требует обязательно наличия и вставки, и обновления. Возможно, это дело вкуса, но для подобных запросов он настолько удобнее апдейта, что я уже забыл, когда писал апдейт последний раз (за исключением тривиальных случаев типа `update table set column = 123 where id = 456`).

Comment: @Dmitry дело не вкуса, а использования инструментов по назначению. у merge предназначение несколько другое, чем просто с его помощью обычные update запросы писать

Answer (score 0):

Можно через хранимую процедуру

```js
CREATE PROCEDURE `my`()
begin
  for item in (select order.id_goods, sum(order.count) as count
   from order
   group by order.id_goods)
  loop
    update goods set goods.count = goods.count - item.count;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему благодаря комментарию [teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran)

```
create procedure 'OrderFill' (IN count INT)
begin
set sql_safe_updates = 0; //в процедуре было несколько команд помимо той, что ниже, но в ответе они не уместны
update Goods g, Orders_has_Goods o set g.amount = g.amount - o.quantity where g.id_goods = o.Goods_id_goods and o.Orders_id_orders = count;
end
```